# During promotion of electron in $3p$ orbital before hybridisation, why does it get promoted to $3d$ orbital and not $4s$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, orbitals

During the hybridization of certain elements such as phosphorus during the formation of $\rm PCl_5$, the atom first gets changed to the excited state. In the case of $\rm PCl_5$, the paired electron in the 3s orbital gets promoted to 3d orbital. Similarly in $\rm SF_6$, the paired electrons in 3s and 3p orbitals get promoted to the 3d orbital. Why does this happen? Shouldn't the electrons get promoted to the 4s orbital as it is lower in energy than the 3d orbital, and also nearer to the ground state orbitals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ground state of phosphorus is  $\mathrm{[Ne] 3s^2 3p^3}$.

In order for $\mathrm{PCl_5}$ to exist with the molecular shape we know from experiment, a hybrisation occurs in $\mathrm{P}$'s valence electrons, that is:

$$\mathrm{sp^4}$$

These are five atomic orbitals, identical in all respects.

This explains the molecule's [trigonal bipyridal shape](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/269233/molecular-orbitals-and-nodal-symmetry/269257#269257), shown at the bottom of that (an answer of mine) link.

> Shouldn't the electrons get promoted to the 4s orbital as it is lower
> in energy than the 3d orbital, and also nearer to the ground state
> orbitals?

The $\mathrm{d}$ orbital doesn't enter the equation, if we assume a set of five $\mathrm{sp^4}$ hybridised orbitals. The $\mathrm{sp^4}$ have energies in between the $\mathrm{s}$ and $\mathrm{p}$ energy levels.

Comment: $sp^4$?........

Comment: @ACB Five atomic orbitals, each with one unpaired electron 'occupying' them. $5$ valence electrons, and $5$  $\mathrm{sp^4}$ hybridised electrons.

Comment: hmm there is only 3 p orbitals so where did the extra p come from?

Comment: @Buraian   There are no 'extra' $p$: the valence electrons for $\mathrm{P}$ are $\mathrm{3s^2 3p^3}$. That's FIVE electrons.

Comment: I know only $sp^3d$ after $sp^3$.

Comment: @ABC for the most part $\mathrm{sp^3d}$ is now condidered 'old hat' Usually the difference in energy between, s,p and d orbitals is way too big to alllow spd hybridisations. I got seriously 'burnt' over at the chem.SE site for suggesting a $\mathrm{sp^3d^2}$ hybridisation (for the $\mathrm{Al^{3+}}$ solvated ion) And I'm a chemist!

Comment: @Gert does that mean P does not undergo excitation and the $3s$ electrons remain as it is?

Comment: @Dan No, not at all. Hybridisation causes atomic orbitals of mixed $s,p$ character to form. The case of the famous carbon $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybrids (which explains the shape of the $\text{CX}_4$ molecules) is given in the link I provided. And more mathematically also here: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Inorganic_Chemistry_(Housecroft)/05%3A_Bonding_in_polyatomic_molecules/5.2%3A_Valence_Bond_Theory_-_Hybridization_of_Atomic_Orbitals/5.2D%3A_sp3_Hybridization

Comment: @Gert I meant to ask whether the electron gets promoted or not. Does it get promoted? Thanks for all the information you provided about hybridization.

Comment: @Dan It depends on what you call 'promotion'. The energy levels of the $\mathrm{sp^4}$ orbitals is inbetween those of the $\mathrm{3s}$ and $\mathrm{3p}$ levels. Would you call that 'promotion'? (It's an awkward term in this context...)

Comment: @Gert The 'promotion' I speak about is the excitation of the electron that happens _before_ hybridization, not the energy of the electron after hybridization.
For example, the $3s$ orbital of phosphorus has two electrons, paired. Due to the energy released during the overlap of orbitals of Cl, the paired $3s$ electron gets excited to the $3d$ orbital, and as a result, we get sp3d hybridization. Since you said  sp4 hybridization takes place, that means the electron must remain in $3s$ orbital itself before hybridization. Does the excitation before hybridization happen at all?

Comment: @Dan *"Does the excitation before hybridization happen at all?"* I find the question really unuseful. The electrons in the $\mathrm{3s}$ and $\mathrm{3p}$ orbitals end up in hydrid orbitals of mixed $\mathrm{sp}$ character, i.e. $\mathrm{sp^4}$. I don't think 'promotion' of the $\mathrm{3s^2}$ enters the equation.

Comment: Incidentally, for those who still cling to the debunked $\mathrm{sp^3d}$ concept, go to chemistry.SE and type "sp3d hybridisation" in the search box. No one serious still believes in it...